# Nested routes and no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I have three resources - `users`, `lists` and `items`. I just nested `lists` under `users` and updated my links accordingly, but I am getting two errors from rspec which are a complete mystery to me. Everything worked before I nested the routes.

I'm a total newbie to rails and any help is thus much appreciated!

```
  1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Lists controller submitting to the destroy action 
     Failure/Error: before { delete user_list_path(user, FactoryGirl.create(:list)) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:84:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages profile page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}
     # ./app/views/shared/_user_info.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__user_info_html_erb__1836116684083464018_70145329446120'
     # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___902249955135429148_70145329432180'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :lists, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
  end
  resources :items, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :lists
```

list.rb

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :link, :list_id, :title
  belongs_to :list
```

**UPDATE**

user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:l1) { FactoryGirl.create(:list, user: user, name: "Foo") }
    let!(:l2) { FactoryGirl.create(:list, user: user, name: "Bar") }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

    describe "lists" do
      it { should have_content(l1.name) }
      it { should have_content(l2.name) }
      it { should have_content(user.lists.count) }
    end
  end

  describe "lists page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:l1) { FactoryGirl.create(:list, user: user, name: "Foo") }
    let!(:i1) { FactoryGirl.create(:item, list: l1, title: "Shirt") }

    before { visit user_list_path(user, l1) }

    it { should have_content(i1.title) }
    it { should have_content(l1.items.count) }
  end
...
```

**UPDATE 2**

users_contoller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @lists = @user.lists
    @list = current_user.lists.build if signed_in?
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to Wishlistt!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first error is telling you that the user you are creating is invalid because a user with that email has already been created. (Failing an email uniqueness validation ) You can get around this by changing your user factory to sequence the email so that every record is unique like so:

```
sequence(:email) { |n| "User#{n}@example.com"}
```

The second test fails for this exact same reason. Since your user record is nil, you are essentially trying to grab a non-existant record from your database. It is telling you that in the line:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil}
```

By having the user = nil, the following is happening in your show action:

```
your implementation will look something like this:
#####
@user = User.find(params[:id])
#####
```

since params[:id] = nil, you get

```
User.find(nil)
```

Which will fail since there is no user record with an id of nil. The rest of your implementation should be fine.

Comment: Thanks - it worked great for the first error! However, the second error still shows?

Comment: The second test is failing because you don't have a user. Can you reproduce your test code so that I can take a look at what is going wrong?

Comment: It occurred to me that it only fails when user is not signed in. Any suggestions? Im clueless

Comment: You don't have a user record when you think that you do. In the middle of the test that is failing write `puts user` run the tests and you should get `nil`. If the factory is not creating a user for each test then I would change the lazy loaded let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } to the bang version `let!(...)` If they are not signed in and you are trying to find a user record of a not signed in person then it should be obvious why this is failing

Comment: Thanks for your help! It appeared however, that I used a path for current_user, which is function to return the user that is currently signed in. When the user wasn't signed in, this returned nil.